# gnuplot - Histogram with histeps connects bars

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

This is a minimal working example of the code I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << EOF

set term postscript portrait color enhanced 
set encoding iso_8859_1
set output 'temp.ps'
set grid noxtics noytics noztics front
set size ratio 1
set multiplot
set lmargin 9; set bmargin 3; set rmargin 2; set tmargin 1

n=32    #number of intervals
max=13. #max value
min=-3.0    #min value
width=(max-min)/n        #interval width
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0

set boxwidth width
set style fill solid 0.25 noborder

plot "< awk '{if (3.544068>=\$1) {print \$0}}' /data_file" u (hist(\$2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "red" lt 1 lw 1.5 notitle


EOF
```

which gets me this:

[image: boxes]

What I need is to use `histeps` instead, but when I change `boxes` for `histeps` in the `plot`command above, I get:

[image: histeps]

What is going on here??

Here's the [data_file](http://pastebin.com/JCD2Um52). Thank you!

---

EDIT: If having `histeps` follow the actual outer bars limits instead of interpolating values in between (like `boxes`does) is not possible, then how could I draw **just** the outline of a histogram made with `boxes`?

---

EDIT2: As usual mgilson, your answer is beyond useful. One minor glitch though, this is the output I'm getting which when I combine both plots with the command:

```
plot "< awk '{if (3.544068>=\$1) {print \$0}}' data_file" u (hist(\$2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "red" lt 1 lw 1.5 notitle, \
"<python pyscript.py data_file" u 1:2 w histeps lc rgb "red" lt 1 lw 1.5 notitle
```

[image: histo_shifted]

Something appears to be shifting the output of the `python` script and I can't figure out what it might be.
(Fixed in comments)

Comment: It looks like gnuplot is interpolating between points by putting the step halfway between, which is probably what it is intended to do (http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/intro/style-e.html has some explanation).  Maybe you can try adding zeros to the data file where there are no data points?

Comment: Nope, given the length of my real data file that is not doable. Any way I could mimic the `histeps` output using `boxes`? The catch: there's more than one histogram being plotted so it needs to be transparent.

Comment: Are you opposed to using other tools (such as python -- instead of `awk`?)

Comment: I am not opposed at all, but using Python **would** be a complication for me right now. Couldn't it be FORTRAN?

Comment: Let me clarify: I'm quite pressed with time and unless it's a super simple Python code, I'd rather code in FORTRAN which is my go-to language for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binning is quite easy if you have python + numpy.  It's a *very* popular package, so you should be able to find it in your distribution's repository if you're on Linux.

```
#Call this script as:
#python this_script_name.py 3.14159 data_file.dat

import numpy as np
import sys

n=32         #number of intervals
dmax=13.     #max value
dmin=-3.0    #min value


#primitive commandline parsing
limit = float(sys.argv[1])   #first argument is the limit
datafile = sys.argv[2]       #second argument is the datafile to read

data = []    #empty list
with open(datafile) as f:  #Open first commandline arguement for reading.
    for line in f:            #iterate through file returning 1 line at a time
        line = line.strip()   #remove whitespace at start/end of line
        if line.startswith('#'): #ignore comment lines.
            continue
        c1,c2 = [float(x) for x in line.split()] #convert line into 2 floats and unpack
        if limit >= c1:  #Check to make sure first one is bigger than your 3.544...
            data.append(c2) #If c1 is big enough, then c2 is part of the data

counts, edges = np.histogram(data,               #data to bin
                             bins=n,             #number of bins
                             range=(dmin,dmax),  #bin range
                             normed=False        #numpy2.0 -- use `density` instead
                             )
centers = (edges[1:] + edges[:-1])/2.  #average the bin edges to the center. 

for center,count in zip(centers,counts):  #iterate through centers and counts at same time
    print center,count                    #write 'em out for gnuplot to read.
```

and the gnuplot script looks like:

```
set term postscript portrait color enhanced 
set output 'temp.ps'
set grid noxtics noytics noztics front
set size ratio 1
set multiplot
set lmargin 9 
set bmargin 3
set rmargin 2 
set tmargin 1

set style fill solid 0.25 noborder

plot "<python pyscript.py 3.445 data_file" u 1:2 w histeps lc rgb "red" lt 1 lw 1.5 notitle
```

I'll explain more when I get a little more free time ...

Comment: Wow man, this is just too much, you're starting to make me feel guilty coming up with these elaborated answers. I'll have to buy you a beer someday :)
PD: There's a minor glitch, I commented on it above.

Comment: I think I got it, the second to last line shows `print i*width+dmin-width/2,data[i]` when apparently it should be `print i*width+dmin+width/2,data[i]`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Gabriel -- python is simple enough.  You're right about the second to last line (I just checked against the updated version I just posted).  If you have `numpy` installed, or can get it from your repos, I would *highly* suggest you use the alternative version of the python code.  It will probably be more efficient and (more importantly), less buggy/more robust.  I also commented almost every line to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you @mgilson, that new script works even better. Could I ask just one more question? How can I pass more arguments to the python script? I want to pass the number (3.544..) so I can use the script with other limits. I've been looking around but I can't seem to be able to get it done..

Comment: @Gabriel -- Sure.  We can pass it as a commandline argument just as we do the datafile.  For example, `python pyscript.py 3.544 data_file` -- Here `3.544` is `sys.argv[1]` and `data_file` is `sys.argv[2]`.  I'll edit above to reflect this -- If you really want to, we can add true commandline parsing (rather than prehistoric unpacking of `sys.argv`).  It would only be a few lines of code provided that you have `argparse` -- which is again quite easy to get if you don't have it already.

Comment: Yes, the bins are always the same. My problem is that I can't seem to get the `python`script to use the passed variable. I can't even get it to print it out to the screen.

Comment: @Gabriel -- remember, everything python prints to stdout gets gobbled up by gnuplot since gnuplot is reading the stdout stream to get the data.  If you want to actually see something from python when it's being called in the gnuplot script, you might be able to accomplish that if you write to sys.stdout:  `sys.stdout.write(str(whatever)+'\n')`

Comment: Ohh I see now! Wonderful mgilson, thank you so so much. I'll let you continue with your life now, sorry for being a bit needy :)

Comment: @Gabriel -- No problem.  I love gnuplot and I love python.  They're 2 of my favorite things.  (Surprisingly, I like Fortran [Note that writing it in all caps is now quite out of style] and C as well -- but not C++ or perl -- yuck).